# How to raise an event on tcplistener.accepttcpclient

Tags: c#, events, tcplistener

I am now designing an Tcp Server. I want to trigger an event when a client connects to my server. How can be done?

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer at the moment. We don't know what you've tried, what aspect of raising an event is giving you problems, etc. Do you understand how events work in C#? Do you have the TCP server already accepting clients at all? What's stopping you from raising an event at the point where `AcceptTcpClient` returns?

Comment: I am trying to design a Tcp Server. I just want to raise an event when a client connects to my server. It can be done or not?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Just raise an event when `AcceptTcpClient` returns. Again - what's stopping you from implementing this already? Have you done research on how to raise events in C#?

Comment: I can raise an event but what EventArg should I send as an argument? By default TcpListener does not have any EventArgs. Do I have to create my own EventArgs?

Comment: It's your event - do what you want with it. Define your own `EventArgs` subclass if you want, or just use plain `EventArgs` if there isn't any extra information you want to convey. It's really unclear what you're trying to ask here...

Comment: @JonSkeet, I already answered my question. Thanks for your explanations

Comment: To be honest, I don't think it's a very helpful question/answer pair. The question is very lacking in detail, and the answer is simply code with almost no explanation. Hopefully asking the question helped you think things through, but I don't personally think this is going to help other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Server
{
    private TcpListener _server;
    private bool _isServerWorking = false;
    private TcpClient _client;

    public Server(string host, int port)
    {
        var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(host);
        _server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
    }

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        _server.Start();
        _isServerWorking = true;
        while(_isServerWorking)
        {
            _client = await _server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            ServerConnectedEventArgs args = new ServerConnectedEventArgs(_client);
            OnServerConnected(args);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ConnectClientsThredProc, _client);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _isServerWorking = false;
        _server.Stop();
    }


    private static void ConnectClientsThredProc(object obj)
    {
        var client = (TcpClient)obj;
    }



    public event ServerConnectedEventHandler ServerConnectedEvent;
    private void OnServerConnected(ServerConnectedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServerConnectedEvent(this, e);
    }

}
```

Finally, I could find the solution. After receiving a client connection I will raise the event. Here is the event data and event delegate.

```
public class ServerConnectedEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public TcpClient Client { set; get; }
    public ServerConnectedEventArgs(TcpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }
}

public delegate void ServerConnectedEventHandler(object sender, ServerConnectedEventArgs e);
```